# Formatting issues when reading a CSV file using PySpark's spark.read.csv function

Tags: csv, pyspark

I'm trying to read a CSV file using PySpark's `spark.read.csv` function, but the resulting DataFrame has some formatting issues. Specifically, the review column contains extra quotation marks, and some rows seem to be missing data. Here's a sample of the DataFrame:

```py
+--------------------+--------------------+
|              review|           sentiment|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|One of the other ...|            positive|
|"A wonderful litt...| not only is it w...|
|"I thought this w...| but spirited you...|
|Basically there's...|            negative|
|"Petter Mattei's ...| power and succes...|
|"Probably my all-...| but that only ma...|
|I sure would like...|            positive|
|This show was an ...|            negative|
|Encouraged by the...|            negative|
|If you like origi...|            positive|
|"Phil the Alien i...|            negative|
|I saw this movie ...|            negative|
|"So im not a big ...| meaning most of ...|
|The cast played S...|            negative|
|This a fantastic ...|            positive|
|Kind of drawn in ...|            negative|
|Some films just s...|            positive|
|This movie made i...|            negative|
|I remember this f...|            positive|
|An awful film! It...|            negative|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I've tried specifying different options like header and inferSchema, but nothing seems to fix the issue. Can anyone suggest a solution or a workaround?"

Comment: Can you show some rows (specifically the incorrectly inferred ones) with ```df.show(truncate=False)```

Comment: I can't copy it, it seems to contain more words than what is displayed, I'm working on an imdb dataset and I can read it without any problem with pandas.

Comment: Can you try with ```spark.read.option("escape","\"").option("multiLine", "true")```